# Return true if a number is in descending order

Tags: python, function, frequency

For the following function, I'm trying to return True if the digits are in descending order and false if they are not.

The 'digits' must be positive integers

This is my code:

```
def rev_num_sort(digits):
    n = len(digits)
    for i in range n:
        if digits[i] < digits[i+1]
            return False
    return True
```

E.g.

```
print rev_num_sort(321)
True

print rev_num_sort(123)
False
```

I know you can't take the length of an int and I'm getting this error when I run the print statement, but I'm not sure how to work it out without finding the length.

Comment: Looks like you haven't decided if `digits` is an int, str or list yet. Choose one type and stick to it everywhere

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> def rev_num_sort(num):
...     strs = str(num)
...     return strs == "".join(sorted(strs, reverse=True))
... 
>>> rev_num_sort(321)
True
>>> rev_num_sort(123)
False
>>> rev_num_sort(510)
True
```

Using `zip` and `any`, no sorting required:

```
>>> def rev_num_sort(num):
...     strs = str(num)
...     return all(int(x) > int(y) for x, y in zip(strs, strs[1:]))
... 
>>> rev_num_sort(321)
True
>>> rev_num_sort(123)
False
>>> rev_num_sort(510)
True
```

A memory efficient version using `itertools.izip` and iterators:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> def rev_num_sort(num):
...     strs = str(num)
...     it1 = iter(strs)
...     it2 = iter(strs)
...     next(it2)
...     return all(int(x) > int(y) for x, y in izip(it1, it2))
... 
>>> rev_num_sort(321)
True
>>> rev_num_sort(123)
False
>>> rev_num_sort(510)
True
```

Comment: Yep, what I was going to suggest as well.

Comment: thank you works like a treat!

Comment: @Emma glad that helped, you can accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shortcircuiting version that avoids list copies

```
def rev_num_sort(digits):
    digits = str(digits)    # assuming digits is an int/long
    all(digits[i-1] >= j for i, j in enumerate(digits) if i)
```

Answer (score 0):

i would like integer operations, but i have not test the efficiency.

```
def isDigitsOrdered(digits) :
    base = 10
    lastNum = digits % base
    while True:
        base *= 10
        tmpNum = digits % base / (base / 10)
        if 0 == tmpNum and 0 == (digits/base):
            break
        if tmpNum >= lastNum :
            return False
        lastNum = tmpNum
    return True
```

Finally, i test the efficiency by my self, using the case below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import timeit

setup = """
def isDigitsOrdered(digits) :
    base = 10
    lastNum = digits % base
    while True:
        base *= 10
        tmpNum = digits % base / (base / 10)
        if 0 == tmpNum and 0 == (digits/base):
            break
        if tmpNum >= lastNum :
            return False
        lastNum = tmpNum
    return True

def rev_num_sort(digits):
    digits = str(digits)    # assuming digits is an int/long
    return all(digits[i-1] >= j for i, j in enumerate(digits) if i)

testdigits = (1234444444566788888999999999, 9999999998888876654444444321, 123456, 55667890)
gc.enable()
"""
testNum = 1000000
t1 = timeit.Timer("""
    for d in testdigits :
        isDigitsOrdered(d)
""",  setup)
print t1.timeit(testNum)

t2 = timeit.Timer("""
    for d in testdigits :
        rev_num_sort(d)
""",  setup)
print t2.timeit(testNum)
```

The result of the test is :
**16.6870310307

45.7681000233**
which showes the time cost by integer operation is much faster than the string ones with *GC enable*.

Comment: Using integer operations is only more efficient in cases where you can  avoid converting to base 10 - this can be particularly bad for large longs. Since you are effectively converting to base 10 here, you might as well take advantage of `str`

Comment: @gnibbler My test shows the result, if there anything i missed, please help me figure it out.

Comment: Looks like you are checking for strictly ascending digits. However, you are correct - you do get to short circuit, so it can be faster in that case. I note that you're returning `False` even for equal digits, so the only case running to completion is `123456`. You should change your code to match the descending requirement for the benchmark, and perhaps run the difference cases separately to highlight the cases which are faster/slower for the different algorithms.

Comment: @gnibbler Your are right, i replace the *>=* with *>*, result get to **78.009221077**, even more slower. By the way, separate testcases do not affect the test result, it even became more slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
def descending(n):
    prevDplace = False
    while n > 0:
        n *= 0.1
        currDplace = n%1
        n = n - currDplace
        if prevDplace:
            if prevDplace > currDplace:
                return False
        else:
            prevDplace = currDplace
    return True


def rev_num_sort(digits):
    digits = str(digits)    # assuming digits is an int/long
    all(digits[i-1] >= j for i, j in enumerate(digits) if i)
```

Here are some performance comparisons of gnibbler's and mine (similar to Mr C's) based on a timeit of 10000 times on both (results respectively in the tuple):

```
1234444444566788888999999999
9999999998888876654444444321
```

`descending`:

```
(0.48712682723999023, 0.8589978218078613)
```

`gnibbler`:

```
(0.1695241928100586, 0.69327712059021)
```

I found this quite suprising, the string approach is much faster!

Comment: Your version is float version not the integer one, so it indicates float operation is much slower than string.